# Can the database table be ordered such that NULL values appear at the bottom?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database table called 'Customers' like this:

```
Sl     Name    Profession
1      ABC     Doctor
2      QWE     Engineer
3      ERT     null
4      DEF     Doctor
5      JGJ     null
```

I want to order this table as all the names with professions are at the beginning and names without profession(null) at the bottom, like this:

```
Sl     Name    Profession
1      ABC     Doctor
2      QWE     Engineer
4      DEF     Doctor
5      JGJ     null
3      ERT     null
```

Is there any query to do this? Thanks in advance..

Comment: In SQL tables are `un-ordered sets` and the simple answer to your question is "no". To ensure a query result is in a desired order you need to use the `order by` clause.

Comment: @Used_By_Already That's not what this question is about.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I responded to a question that was entitled: *Can the database table be ordered without using ORDER BY query?*  & the answer to that is: "no"

Comment: @Used_By_Already I get your point, I edited the title with something more appropriate, because the question is clearly about NULLS last in MySQL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah.. i know 'order by' query. but, i want to order the table as null values coming at the bottom. maybe, the first title was wrong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL`s in MySQL (and most flavors of SQL) sort first by default, not last.  One general way to force `NULL` values to the bottom is to use a `CASE` or `IF` expression:

```
SELECT
    Sl, Name, Profession
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    IF(Profession IS NOT NULL, 0, 1),
    Sl;
```

Comment: I want to order the table based on  'Sl' column, but the null values should come at last. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Yes, just add a second level of sorting using the `Sl` column _after_ placing the NULLs at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

use `order by`

```
select * from table_name
order by case when Profession is not null then 1 else 2 end
```

NO DB engine provide you order rows without using order by